# How to detect if two Android devices are near each other without using GPS?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, wifi

I am planning a social app that needs a functionality to detect when two people are really close to each other, and preferably something that would be hard to cheat. I know I could use GPS but since there are GPS spoofing apps and the accuracy is not as narrow as I would need (for instance, two people on the same building but many floors apart should yield negative) I wanted to see if I could do it through WiFi or Bluetooth.

Is it possible to have two Android devices detect each other on the same wifi network from an app? No other information besides their presence is necessary.

I know Bluetooth can easily be done if the devices agree on the connection everytime. But I needed automatic detection, meaning the devices would accept the connection only once, and everytime they get close to each other the detection would be automatic without asking for permissions, and without requiring one of them to perform any actions to scan for bluetooth devices. I assume this is not possible for privacy reasons, right? Although no exchange of data is necessary, just the presence.

If anyone has any suggestions of other ways to achieve this, feel free to suggest. I don't need details about the code, just to know what is possible and what isn't and what do I need to look into (for instance libraries or components from the sdk).

I know detecting devices unconditionally is very unlikely to exist, for obvious reasons, but what I am looking for should go through an initial "handshake" or permission between the two devices, in order to enable the detection to happen (over a limited time window of maybe a couple of days), so I guess it may be possible, although I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can check this API https://developers.google.com/nearby

Comment: The new Corona app i think.